# Trigger build of one maven project from another

Tags: java, maven

I need to trigger build of a project from another project locally. Want to set-up an endpoint which would trigger the start of the build of another Maven project.

One way I can think of is to create a bat file with commands to start the build of the 2nd project. And with `Processbuilder`, run the bat file from project-1.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: There is not Maven support for something like this (other than, of course, using a multi module project).

Comment: can you tell me how to do it with a multi module project? is it with a parent-child project structure?

Comment: You have a one large project, with a main POM and different modules (subprojects) in subdirectories. Then you can build them all together in the correct order by invoking Maven from the directory of the main POM.